# Not able to run .vbs file from jenkins which is having excel script

Tags: jenkins, vbscript, hp-uft

I’m new to Jenkins and now I'm doing basic level of execution. And I need your help resolve my issue. Issue Description: I’m trying to run the .VBS file by using jenkins and getting below error:

C:\Users\Amar\Desktop\Test_Sample.vbs(3, 2) Microsoft Excel: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file ‘C:\Users\Amar\Desktop\New.xlsx’.

**There are several possible reasons:**

- The file name or path does not exist.
- The file is being used by another program.
- The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently
  open workbook.

I have not opened any excel file and path also correct.

please find below batch command : CScript “C:\Users\Amar\Desktop\Test_Sample.vbs”

And in Test_Sample.vbs file having:

```
Dim ExcelObj, WbookObj, mysheet
Set ExcelObj= CreateObject("excel.application")  
Set WbookObj= ExcelObj.workbooks.open("C:\Users\Amar\Desktop\New.xlsx")
Set mysheet= ExcelObj.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 
ExcelObj.Visible = False  
ExcelRowCount = mysheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count    
For Iterator = 2 To ExcelRowCount  
    ModuleName   =   Ucase(Trim(mysheet.Cells(Iterator,1)))  
    ExecutionFlag = Ucase(Trim(mysheet.Cells(Iterator,2)))   
    if (moduleName="Raj") Then   
        Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application")
        If qtApp.launched True then   
            qtApp.Launch   
        End If  
        qtApp.Visible = True   
        qtApp.Open "F:\Jenkins_Jobs\OnCall_Sanity_Automation\DriverScript\Sample",  False   
        Set QTPTest=qtApp.Test    
        QTPTest.Run 'Run the Test QTPTest.Close   
        qtApp.quit
        Set qtApp = Nothing 
    else
        MsgBox "Name not exists"
    End If
Next
```

Please help me to resolve the issue.

Thanks, Amar

**Update**

Console Output:

> Building in workspace C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Excel_Test [Excel]
>   $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkin02.bat (C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Excel_Test>CScript )
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test_Sample.vbs" 
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test_Sample.vbs(3, 2) Microsoft Excel:
>   Microsoft Excel cannot access the file
>   C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New.xlsx.   There are several possible reasons:
>   ** The file name or path does not exist.**   The file is being used by another program.   The workbook you are trying to save has the same
>   name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: Pls update your post with Jenkins console output...

Comment: Depending on how you set up Jenkins, odds are its permissions can't see the content of the `Users` folder.  Move the file into `C:\temp` or similar and retry.

Comment: Console Output: 
Building in workspace C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Excel_Test
[Excel] $ cmd /c call C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\jenkin02.bat
(C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Excel_Test>CScript )
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test_Sample.vbs" 
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test_Sample.vbs(3, 2) Microsoft Excel: Microsoft Excel cannot access the file 
C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\New.xlsx. 
There are several possible reasons:
** The file name or path does not exist.**
 The file is being used by another program.
 The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.

Comment: I agree with Dave. Looks like your Excel file is under Admin profile. So I would suggest to move to somewhere under C drive and give it a try.

Comment: I tried with different machine and diff path then also its not working :( .

Comment: Which other diff paths you have tried...? Try to put your Excel under "C:\Jenkins\".

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on 64-bit Windows Operating System.

Then go to

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemProfile
```

Above Folder and create an empty Folder, and name it "Desktop" inside "systemProfile".

**For doing this, you need system admin access**

After creating the folder as mentioned, then run your build in Jenkins.

Comment: "Desktop" folder is already there in the mentioned location. Still I'm facing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run the jenkins job in command prompt on a slave,it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Set Full control permissions for below  path "Desktop" directory

"C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop " (for 64 bit Windows) or 
"C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop " (for 32 bit Windows)

If Desktop directory in present please create and give Full control permissions